# How do you delete an object event source in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have added a event source as such:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        getInactive(start, end, timezone, callback);
        });         
}
```

the events inside that have id:0

If I do .fullCalendar(removeEvent, 1) -- it removes data only from existing view and then if we browse back to it, it is already read.

Thus the source object needs to be removed, but we never specified a source id? I've tried sending the same data again with removeEventSource and it didn't quite work. I need help removing all instances of this object that is dynamically created. Thanks,

Comment: have you tried `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents').fullCalendar('removeEventSources')`?

Comment: as the docs say, keep a reference to the function as a variable instead of declaring it anonymously.  Then you can pass that variable to the removeEventSource method. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEventSource says "The source parameter is rather flexible. You can provide an event source’s id/Array/URL/Function or you can specify the full Event Source Object."

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that removes everything from the current view, but it doesn't fully remove the EventSource.

Comment: @ADyson I did x = function() then did removeEventSources, x and it seemed to work will follow up if there are other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //delete
        $this.$modal.find('.delete-event').show().end().find('.save-event').hide().end().find('.modal-body').empty().prepend(form).end().find('.delete-event').click(function () {
            $this.$calendarObj.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (ev) {
                return (ev._id == calEvent._id);
            });


             $.ajax({
                 url : 'index.php',
                 data: 'action=delete&id='+calEvent.id,
                 type: "POST",
             });

        });
```